# slack timing and system timing

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I want to gather output of a particular slack channel on my localmachine daily 2 time morning 5:30 and evening 5:30. The ts of the slack server cannot be changed into the local ts. The originator of our timestamp is our linux’s time and the server ts is set using server settings.

how can I change timestamp of slack to dd—mm—year.

Is there any way where this can be made possible. any idea or clue will help.

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly is it you want to achieve and what is your problem. Please also add the code you already have. Thanks.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I need to change slack timestamp to `d-mm-yyyy`.

Comment: Still not really sure what help you need, in which context does the "timestamp" occur on Slack, that you need changed? Is it in a message on Slack? Or are you receiving messages from Slack with your app, or, or, ...

Comment: We are receiving automated slack messages on slack via `incoming  webhook  APP`

Comment: @ErikKalkoken ts per message should be changed

Comment: Your additional comments have not really helped to clarify matters. Please consider rewriting / extending your question, so people can understand what you are asking.
e.g. asking to change the ts per message makes no sense, its in standard [UNIX epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which can be easily translated to any local time.